# Вставка данных, пропуская повторяющиеся ключи?

Tags: postgresql

В таблице jobs, уникальный индекс по двум полям type_id,data_id.
При вставке в таблицу через select запрос, некоторые ключи повторяются, и в итоге возникает ошибка и ничего не записывается вообще. А нужно чтобы записывались те записи, где ключи не повторяются.

```
INSERT INTO jobs (type_id,data_id,status) \
        ( SELECT 1,id,1 FROM table1  WHERE id=37)
```

Comment: Ну например вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009584/how-to-emulate-insert-ignore-and-on-duplicate-key-update-sql-merge-with-po  а вообще самый прямой путь - сделать select таким что бы он в принципе не возвращал того, что не надо вставлять, добавить условие not exists например

Comment: Да, сработало добавление ON CONFLICT (type_id,data_id) DO NOTHING. В новой версии postgreSql это нативно.